# Clearing screen in Python (when using Pythonwin)

Tags: python

When I use something like Pythonwin I always have to highlight everything in the debugging window and press delete to get rid of everything. Is there a way to make the program autoclear the debug window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import os

os.system("cls")
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not work. It brought up a command prompt screen which instantly closed then the code ran as usual without clearing the previous run.

Comment: it would work if you ran your program from the command prompt

Comment: I am using Pythonwin as designated in the OP, using the debug window

Comment: @IAmBatman: You are the OP. If it doesn't work why did you accept it?

Answer (score 2):

For clarity to anyone who comes across this old question.

PythonWin's interactive shell window can be cleared by highlighting all the text and then pressing delete just like it were a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that works for Pythonwin:

```
import subprocess

def cls():
  doc=subprocess.sys.stdout.GetDocument()
  Editor=doc.GetEditorView()
  Editor.SetSel(-1,0)
  Editor.ReplaceSel("")

cls()
```